# The independence between stochastic integral and sigma-algebra

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-integrals

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P} )$ be the probability space, and {$W_t,0\leq t\leq T$} is a Brownian motion and $\mathcal{F_t}^W$ is the canonical filtration.

For the $f(t)\in L^2([0, T])$(a deterministic function), we can define the stochastic integral $\int_s^tf(u)dW_u$,where $0<s<t<T$.

So I am wondering if the $\int_s^tf(u)dW_u$ is independent with the $\mathcal{F_s}$?

Because by the definition of the stochastic integral, $\int_s^tf(u)dW_u$ is the $L^2$-limit of the stochastic integral of simple process, which could have the form like $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f(u_i)(W_{u_{i+1}}-W_{u_i})$, where $\{u_{i}\}_{i=1}^n$ is partition of  the interval $[s, t]$: $s=u_0<u_1<...<u_n=t$.

For $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f(u_i)(W_{u_{i+1}}-W_{u_i})$, we know that it is independent with the $\mathcal{F_s}$. So I just want to know if the independence still holds between the $L^2$-limit and the $\sigma$-algebra.

Thank you!

Comment: "So I just want to know if the independence still holds between the L2-limit and the σ-algebra." It does.

Comment: @Did Thanks! Could you please give more details?

Answer (score 1):

Of course. In order to see this, just write that for $A\in F_s$,

\begin{align}
E\left[
1_A \int_s^t fdW
\right] &= \lim E\left[1_A
\sum f(u_i)(W_{u_{i+1}} - W_{u_i})
\right] \\&= \lim E\left[1_A\right] E\left[
\sum f(u_i)(W_{u_{i+1}} - W_{u_i})\right]
\\&= E\left[
1_A\right] 
E\left[\int_s^t fdW\right]
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks! But I am still confused because that I am not sure if the fact that a random variable $X$ being independent with a set $A$ is equivalent the fact that $\int_AXd\mathbb{P}=\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{P}(A)$

Comment: I know that the independence can deduce $\int_AXd\mathbb{P}=\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{P}(A)$, but I am not sure if they are equivalent. Could you please explain more details? Thank you!

Comment: This does not prove independence.